# Symbol indicating a value equal to or greater than a number

Tags: american-english, translation, numbers

I am working on translation of numbers and came across this representation of "5 or greater" as "5+". My question is whether or not there is a term for the "+" sign that represents the value as being equal to or greater than the number shown.

Comment: All usages I've seen of 5+ have genetally meant more than five. I've never seen it being used in the way you are asking for.

Comment: On freeway signs in Los Angels, 2+ in the HOV lane means 2 or more, confusingly to me.

Comment: `>=5` would be understood by most folks in the US.

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding your question, but 5+ is usually articulated as "5 plus" in speech and, at least in the US, means five or more.  Perhaps @MoziburUllah is speaking to its meaning in the UK?

Comment: The question is whether or not there is a term for the "+" sign in this usage. The grammar police or their trusted agents should have a satisfyingly verbose opinion. This I am looking forward to.

Comment: Collins dictionaries call it a "plus sign" in this context https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/plus-sign

Comment: It's been discussed on Mathematics Stack Exchange, where they say 5000+ means "5000 or more" (but while it's common in everyday usage, it's not standard mathematical notation). And they call it a "plus sign". https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480123/plus-sign-after-a-number-means

Comment: Let me provide some more context. The reason why I'm looking for this term is because I'm currently doing research on how to translate strings similar to "5+" since I believe translation of this as a whole unit can be different between languages.

My understanding of "5+" is "5 or more". This question is tagged as "american-english" to refer to the origin of my example, however, I'm not an expert and can't say with certainty that this is the correct interpretation.

Edit: Didn't know pressing "enter" saves my comment.